# Issue reusing the same view controller in navigation stack | Swift

Tags: swift

Essentially I have 4 view controller that switch from one to the next by using the following code:

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcontroller1") as! viewcontroller1       
controller.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Close", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.closeAction))
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

This works well until I have to switch from `viewcontroller4` back to `viewcontroller1`. I don't need to reuse the same `viewcontroller1` but instead call a fresh version of it. On push how can I reset the navigation stack and call a fresh version of `viewcontroller1`?

Comment: "reset the navigation stack" <--- do you mean you want to pop off everything on the stack, and change the root view controller to a fresh `viewcontroller1`?

Comment: Yes, can you please show how this can be done?

Comment: Help yourself by searching for navigationcontroller clear stack.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have already instantiated a new `viewcontroller1`:

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcontroller1")
```

One way is:

```
navigationController?.setViewControllers([controller], animated: true)
```

This will give you a "push" animation.

Another way is:

```
// index 0 is the root view controller
navigationController?.viewControllers[0] = controller
navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

This will give you a "pop" animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the whole stack like this (added some extra safety with your optionals):

```
if let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "viewcontroller1") as? viewcontroller1 {
  self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([controller], animated:false)
}
```

The key is `setViewControllers(_:animated:)`. If for some reason you did want to reuse your first controller again, you could look into `popToRootController()` in `UINavigationController`.